# How to Find the number of password entries that are on the server? in unix

Tags: users, password

Find the number of password entries that are on the server? in UNIX

Comment: Do you mean user accounts? Or do you mean lines in `/etc/shadow`? Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of lines in a file, simply use `wc`. To look at user accounts on a system, I recommend `getent passwd`, though there are many other equally valid ways of getting at this information. You can combine the two by passing the output of `getent` through `wc`:

```
# getent passwd | wc -l
```

to get a number representing the total number of user accounts available to the system. This is not necessarily the number of user accounts that can be logged in to or that are defined locally, but it will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can also count users with passwords in linux using /etc/shadow file:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; empty = 0; cnt = 0; } { if ($2 !~ "!" && $2 !~ "*") { if ($2 !~ "") emty++; else cnt++; } } END { print "passwords: " cnt "\nempty passwords: " empty }' /etc/shadow
```

On  FreeBSD I think you can use /etc/master.passwd